# yandex map api балун кластера, событие выбора и отображения контента балуна для конкретной точки кластера

Tags: yandex-maps-api

мне необходима реакция на смену пользователем точки на балуне кластера.

```
objectManager.clusters.events.add('balloonopen', function (e) {
  var item = e.get('target');
});
или
objectManager.objects.balloon.events.add('open', function (e) {
  var item = e.get('target');
});
```

срабатывает ожидаемо только один раз на открытие всего балуна

```
objectManager.clusters.balloon.events.add('click', function (e) {
  var item = e.get('target');
});
```

как вариант, но срабатывает при клике в любом месте балуна, тоже ожидаемо, к тому же непонятно как "взять" ид точки кластера, для которой сейчас отображен контент

[objectManager.Balloon](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/objectManager.Balloon.html) приведены события, click там нет, потому смею предположить наличие чтонибудь типа selectionchanged

таки есть ли событие у балуна кластера, которое отправляется при смене пользователем точки из списка кластера?

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку вы не привели примера кода, считаю что речь о примере из песочницы Яндекс: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/clusterer_balloon_open

В таком случае вам достаточно добавить прослушивание клика на балуне с определением активной метки и определять не объект, которому принадлежит та или иная часть балуна, а активный объект, для которого этот балун отображается:

```
clusterer.balloon.events.add('click', function (e) {
    console.log(objectState.cluster.state.get('activeObject'))
});
```